# OpenGL and GLUT in x64 on Windows (Visual C++ 2019)

Tags: opengl, c++, glut

I'm just starting to self-learn OpenGL. I have OpenGL A Primer (2nd edition) by Edward Angel and I found this useful site for setting up OpenGL with Visual Studio 2019 on Windows:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-opengl-with-visual-studio-2019-on-windows-10/

I was able to get an example up and running HOWEVER, only by using a 32 bit configuration. The header file "glut.h" seems to specifically call out 32 bit libraries.  Is it possible to use GLUT with 64 bit builds?  I did some research and couldn't find an answer. It makes me wonder if GLUT is no longer supported or there is a newer version somewhere. The tutorial above points me to https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/glut_downloads.php and it seems quite dated. The most relevant download appears to be glut37data.zip

Summary of questions:

1. Are there GLUT headers/libs/dlls in 64 bit version for Windows? Where?
2. Should I be using GLUT or has it been replaced with something better/newer?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! First you need to know, that there are the old "fixed function" opengl which you can use with glut. Or you use the "new" opengl (I think it was opengl 3.0 and upwards...

Comment: What I usually use to create the window is GLFW together with GLM (math library) or EIGEN. Opengl can be included via GLEW. Then you can use the newest opengl version as far as your GPU supports it.

Comment: One small hint: when you are looking for tutorials and find the command "glBegin(....) " or "glEnd". Then you know, that it is the old opengl

Comment: Thanks @Thomas I'll research GLFW, GLEW and GLM.   If you have any tutorials on these it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

GLUT is outdated and abandoned. However there is a remake of GLUT library and it is called FreeGLUT. You can download sources from official page or complete library with compiled DLLs for windows 32bit and 64bit from here: https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/